# Cannot send int from Server to Client in Socket Programming

Tags: c++, sockets, file-handling

I am new to Socket Programming and trying to make a Server-Client program in which the client first sends the name of a file and then the server opens that file and counts the size of the file and sends the size back to the client.

Although on the Server side, I can calculate the size of the file but not able to send it back to the client.

I'm getting the `filesize` as 0.

Here are the codes :

Server

```
#include<iostream>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int  filesize(char* fname){
    FILE *f=fopen(fname,"r");
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    int len=ftell(f);
    fclose(f);
    //cout<<"\nlength= "<<len;
    return len;


}

int main(){
    int sockid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockid<0){
        cout<<"Failed Creating socket\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int client_size=sizeof(client);
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(8791);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(bind(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server))<0){
        cout<<"Failed binding\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"binded";

    if(listen(sockid,4)<0){
        cout<<"Failed listening\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Listening....\n";
    if((client_socket=accept(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t*)&(client_size)))<0){
        cout<<"Failed accepting\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Connecting\n";



    char fname[]={0};

    int x=recv(client_socket,fname,1024,0);

    cout<<fname<<endl;

    //char fname[]={"a.txt"};
    fname[x]='\0';

    int fsize=filesize(fname);
    cout<<"FILE SIZE : "<<fsize<<endl;

    //int fsize=58;

    if(send(client_socket,&fsize,sizeof(int),0)<0){
        cout<<"failed sending SIZE\n";
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    int sockid=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockid<0){cout<<"Failed creating socket\n";return 0;}


    struct sockaddr_in client;
    client.sin_family=AF_INET;
    client.sin_port=htons(8797);
    client.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if(connect(sockid,(struct sockaddr*)&client,sizeof(client))<0){
        cout<<"Failed connecting\n";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Connected\n";

    cout<<"Enter File name : ";
    char fname[1024];
    cin>>fname;
    if(send(sockid,fname,strlen(fname),0)<0){
        cout<<"Failed receiving\n";
    }


    int  fsize;

    if(recv(sockid,&fsize,sizeof(int),0)<0){
        cout<<"failed receiving file_size\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout<<"\nFILE-SIZE : "<<fsize;  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must debug :) - might help if you send the trailing zero for the string, though.

Comment: `char fname[]={0};` make `fname` an array of ***one*** character.

Comment: but the filename can exceed 1 char !!

Comment: Yes it will, and you tell `recv` that `fname` can be up to `1024`  characters, which is a big problem. Think a little bit on how to create an array of the wanted size... (And remember that `fname[x] = '\0'` can write the 1025:th element!)

Comment: So, this is what I could think of : Make 2 arrays, `fname` of dynamic size depending on what `recv` returns and another of size 1024 and then transfer all the required characters of that array to `fname`.

Comment: Where possible in C++ one should prefer a `std::vector` or `std::string` to a dynamic array.

Comment: But, I am not able to understand why 1024 makes a difference when I'm terminating the `fname[x]='\0'`, when the size of `fname` is less than 1024 and why is it affecting the next `send` ?

Comment: Remember that `recv` will return what is available and this may be less than what you asked for. In the case of something like `recv(sockid,&fsize,sizeof(int),0)` this can be fatal because you may have an integer built from less than `sizeof(int) bytes.

Comment: With a size of 1024, `fname` is valid for the indexes 0 through 1023. Access of `fname[1024]` is out of bounds and undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not able understand that which case is fatal, the one where the size of received data is less than 3rd parameter specified in `recv` OR the case where the size of received data is more. I hope the second one is fatal.

Comment: Say you send the number 123456789 as the file size and integer is 32 bit. If `recv` returns 3, only 3 of the 4 bytes of the integer were read. Since you don't check for this possibility, the length you use will be wrong and there will be some unexpected garbage, the last byte of the length, at the beginning of the file.

Comment: TCP is stream-based, not message-based. If you are sending discrete messages, you have to make certain that the whole message was read before trying to interpret it.

Comment: I got you, thnx !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a byte stream. `send()` and `recv()` can return fewer bytes than requested, so you need to call them in loops to ensure you send/recv all of the bytes you are expecting.

Also, you need to frame your messages in such a way that you know where a message ends and the next message begins.

Also, integers should always be transmitted using fixed-width integer types, and multi-byte integers should always be transmitted in network byte order (big endian), for consistency across platform boundaries.

Try something like this:

Server

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool filesize(const std::string &fname, std::uint32_t &fsize)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fname.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!f)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed opening file\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed seeking file\n";
        fclose(f);
        return false;
    }

    long len = ftell(f);
    fclose(f);

    if (len == -1L)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed getting file size\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (sizeof(long) > sizeof(std::uint32_t))
    {
        if (len > std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max())
        {
            std::cout << "File size exceeds uint32_t max\n";
            return false;
        }
    }

    fsize = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(len);
    return true;
}

int readAll(int sock, void *buffer, int buflen)
{
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
    int x;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        x = recv(sock, ptr, buflen, 0);
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            if (x == 0)
                std::cout << "Client disconnected\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Failed reading socket, error " << errno << "\n";
            return x;
        }

        ptr += x;
        buflen -= x;
    }

    return 1;
}

int readUInt32(int sock, std::uint32_t &value)
{
    int x = readAll(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
    if (x <= 0) return x;
    value = ntohl(value);
    return 1;
}

int readString(int sock, std::string &s)
{
    s.clear();

    // approach 1: null-terminated string

    char buffer[1024];
    int x, offset = 0;

    do
    {
        x = readAll(sock, &buffer[offset], 1);
        if (x <= 0)
            return x;

        if (buffer[offset] == '\0')
            break;

        if (++offset == sizeof(buffer))
        {
            s.append(buffer, offset);
            offset = 0;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    if (offset > 0)
        s.append(buffer, offset);

    return 1;

    // approach 2: length-prefixed string

    std::uint32_t size;
    int x = readUInt32(sock, size);
    if ((x > 0) && (size > 0))
    {
        s.resize(size);
        x = readAll(sock, &s[0], size);
    }

    if (x <= 0)
        return x;

    return 1;
}

bool sendAll(int sock, const void *buffer, int buflen)
{
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(buffer);
    int x;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        x = send(sock, ptr, buflen, 0);
        if (x < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed sending socket, error " << errno << "\n";
            return false;
        }

        ptr += x;
        buflen -= x;
    }

    return true;
}

bool sendBool(int sock, bool value)
(
    std::uint8_t temp = value;
    return sendAll(sock, &temp, sizeof(temp));
}

bool sendUInt32(int sock, std::uint32_t value)
{
    value = htonl(value);
    return sendAll(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
}

int main()
{
    int sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockid < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed creating socket, error " << errno << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int client_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    socklen_t client_size;

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8791);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    socklen_t client_size;

    if (bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed binding socket, error " << errno << "\n";
        close(sockid);
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Binded";

    if (listen(sockid, 4) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed listening socket, error " << errno << "\n";
        close(sockid);
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Listening....\n";

    client_size = sizeof(client);
    if ((client_socket = accept(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &client_size)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed accepting client socket\n";
        close(sockid);
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Client connected\n";

    std::string fname;
    if (readString(client_socket, fname) <= 0)
    {
        close(client_socket);
        close(sockid);
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << fname << "\n";

    std::uint32_t fsize;
    bool success = filesize(fname, fsize);

    if (!sendBool(client_socket, success))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed sending file size reply\n";
    }
    else if (success)
    {
        std::cout << "FILE SIZE : " << fsize << std::endl;      

        if (!sendUInt32(client_socket, fsize))
            std::cout << "Failed sending file size\n";
    }

    close(client_socket);
    close(sockid);

    return 0;
}
```

Client

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int readAll(int sock, void *buffer, int buflen)
{
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
    int x;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        x = recv(sock, ptr, buflen, 0);
        if (x <= 0)
        {
            if (x == 0)
                std::cout << "Server disconnected\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Failed reading socket, error " << errno << "\n";
            return x;
        }

        ptr += x;
        buflen -= x;
    }

    return 1;
}

int readBool(int sock, bool &value)
{
    std::uint8_t temp;
    int x = readAll(sock, &temp, sizeof(temp));
    if (x <= 0) return x;
    value = (temp != 0);
    return 1;
}

int readUInt32(int sock, std::uint32_t &value)
{
    int x = readAll(sock, &value, sizeof(value));
    if (x <= 0) return x;
    value = ntohl(value);
    return 1;
}

bool sendAll(int sock, const void *buffer, int buflen)
{
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(buffer);
    int x;

    while (buflen > 0)
    {
        x = send(sock, ptr, buflen, 0);
        if (x < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed sending socket, error " << errno << "\n";
            return false;
        }

        ptr += x;
        buflen -= x;
    }

    return true;
}

bool sendString(int sock, const std::string &s)
{
    // approach 1: null-terminated string

    return sendAll(sock, s.c_str(), s.size()+1);

    // approach 2: length-prefixed string

    std::uint32_t size = s.size();
    return sendUInt32(sock, size) && sendAll(sock, s.c_str(), size);
}

int main()
{
    int sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockid < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed creating socket, error " << errno << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(8797);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if (connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed connecting socket, error " << errno << "\n";
        close(sockid);
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Connected\n";

    std::cout << "Enter File name : ";
    std::string fname;
    std::getline(std::cin, fname);

    if (!sendString(sockid, fname))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed sending file name\n";
        close(sockid);
        return 0;
    }

    bool success;
    if (readBool(sockid, success) <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed receiving file size reply\n";
        close(sockid);
        return 0;
    }

    if (success)
    {
        std::uint32_t fsize;
        if (readUInt32(sockid, fsize) <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed receiving file size\n";
            close(sockid);
            return 0;
        }

        std::cout << "FILE-SIZE : " << fsize << "\n";   
    }
    else
        std::cout << "FILE-SIZE error\n";

    close(sockid);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `send()` and `recv()` operate on bytes only, so `sendAll()` and `readAll()` take byte counts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte on all platforms, this is dictated by the C++ standard. But a byte is not always 8 bits on all platforms, but that is uncommon nowadays (check `CHAR_BIT` if you need to handle platforms with non-standard byte sizes)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `sizeof()` returns the number of bytes. That is also dictated by the C++ standard